# Best way to use JCA CCI connections - Alternative to Spring CCI Support

Tags: spring, cdi, jca, cci

In our project we have a requirement to connect to IBM IMS and get data. Many of the existing applications are done it through code more coupled with IMS.

In one of the application we are using Spring CCI support and providing the CCIConnectionFactory to the JDBCTemplate and using it in a relational (kind of) manner.

However we are building a new application which is not using Spring framework. We are making use of JAVA CDI and it's aspects. But to integrate it with IMS through CCI I can see Spring is the best option. Anyone have experienced on this CCI connections? What way is the best you think? And any other frameworks in Java you are familiar with - apart from Spring's support?

Appreciate your help and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question 5 Month ago and it was very hard to collect information about jca. If your project works with wildfly or jboss take a look on my [inbound-ra-example](https://github.com/joe-bookwood/inbound-ra-example) project. At first you must know what kind of resource adapter (RA) you need, inbound or outbound. In short, an inbound RA acts as a server for external data and send the data to a message driven bean. An outbound RA is called from an EJB via a connection factory and initiate the connection to the external information system. Read the readme.md of my example project. The inbound RA is much more difficult as an outbound RA. Generate the skeleton of your ra with the ironjacamar codegenerator. I described the process in my example project.

Comment: Thank you Jochen. This helps! We are working with Websphere.

Comment: I remember that the Ironjacamar RA code generator ask me to use CCI. But I think websphere uses not  Ironjacamar as JCA implementation. It's jee standard, so you can generate an inbound or outbound RA with CCI and you can reverse engineer the code to see how it works.